# Where should I place ACRA.init(this);?

Tags: java, android, logging, acra

I started to use ACRA (https://github.com/ACRA/acra) for crash reporting. While testing, everything was perfect. Nonetheless, when I released the app, I saw in the Google Play Console an error that was new to the version that I released, caused by `ACRA.init(this);`:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication 
(ActivityThread.java:6209)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200 (ActivityThread.java:236)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage 
(ActivityThread.java:1784)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7032)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
(RuntimeInit.java:494)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:965)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon (ContextImpl.java:1666)
at android.app.ContextImpl.startService (ContextImpl.java:1611)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService 
(ContextWrapper.java:677)
at org.acra.sender.SenderServiceStarter.startService 
(SenderServiceStarter.java:43)
at org.acra.util.ApplicationStartupProcessor.sendApprovedReports 
(ApplicationStartupProcessor.java:75)
at org.acra.ACRA.init (ACRA.java:230)
at org.acra.ACRA.init (ACRA.java:156)
at org.acra.ACRA.init (ACRA.java:139)
at com.myapplication.MyApplication.onCreate 
(MyApplication.java:132)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate 
(Instrumentation.java:1154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication 
(ActivityThread.java:6204)
```

The content of `MyApplication.java:132` is:

```
ACRA.init(this);
```

This means that initializing ACRA is causing the crash, ironically. To provide some context, this is where I have `ACRA.init(this)`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    ACRA.init(this);
```

I was reading the discussion at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/acra-discuss/XUKJ5dFHBl0 and the I read Malcolm Cooke's proposed solution:

> For the benefit of anyone else I discovered what my problem was.
>
> The class MyDBOpenHelper was being triggered from the onCreate method of a ContentProvider, which gets called before the application class's onCreate method. Resolved it for now by moving the acra init method call within the application class as follows

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);

    ACRA.init(this);
    // some of your own operations before content provider will launch
}
```

Where should I put `ACRA.init(this);`? I have it in `public void onCreate()` but it is throwing this `java.lang.IllegalStateException` to me. So I guess I should try putting it in `protected void attachBaseContext(Context base)`, as Malcolm Cooke suggested. Can anyone confirm what the right place for `ACRA.init(this);` is? Thank you.

**UPDATE 1:**

Chapter 3 of Practical Android: 14 Complete Projects on Advanced Techniques and Approaches ([https://www.amazon.com/dp/B078SK4W1M/ref=dp-kindle-redirect?_encoding=UTF8&btkr=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078SK4W1M)) provides an example of a project using ACRA and in their MyApplication.java file, they use this:

```
package com.wickham.android.crashlog;

import org.acra.annotation.ReportsCrashes;
import org.acra.*;
import android.app.Application;

@ReportsCrashes(
                customReportContent = { ReportField.REPORT_ID,
                                        ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE,
                                        ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME,
                                        ReportField.PACKAGE_NAME, 
                                        ReportField.PHONE_MODEL, 
                                        ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION, 
                                        ReportField.STACK_TRACE,
                                        ReportField.TOTAL_MEM_SIZE,
                                        ReportField.AVAILABLE_MEM_SIZE,
                                        ReportField.DISPLAY,
                                        ReportField.USER_APP_START_DATE,
                                        ReportField.USER_CRASH_DATE,
                                        ReportField.LOGCAT,
                                        ReportField.DEVICE_ID,
                                        ReportField.SHARED_PREFERENCES,
                                        ReportField.CUSTOM_DATA },
                //formKey = "",
                formUri = "https://example.com/crashed.php",
                httpMethod = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Method.POST,
                mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
                resToastText = R.string.msg_crash_text)

public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
        super.onCreate();
        ACRA.init(this);
    }
}
```

They are placing `ACRA.init(this);` in `public void onCreate()`. It works for me while I test. Nonetheless, when I released the app, I already saw a crash in the Google Play Console that was caused by `ACRA.init(this);` as I explained in my question. So I guess I could try placing `ACRA.init(this);` in `protected void attachBaseContext(Context base)`, as Malcolm Cooke suggested. Can anyone clarify this to me?

**UPDATE 2:**

Reading https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup, I see they have this:

```
import org.acra.*;
import org.acra.annotation.*;

@AcraCore(buildConfigClass = BuildConfig.class)
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);

        // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA
        ACRA.init(this);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 3:**

Even when I put it in `attachBaseContext`, ACRA is making my app to crash:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication (LoadedApk.java:1164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6529)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900 (ActivityThread.java:267)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1963)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:109)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:207)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7470)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:524)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:958)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon (ContextImpl.java:1842)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startService (ContextImpl.java:1797)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService (ContextWrapper.java:664)
  at org.acra.sender.SenderServiceStarter.startService (SenderServiceStarter.java:43)
  at org.acra.util.ApplicationStartupProcessor.sendApprovedReports (ApplicationStartupProcessor.java:75)
  at org.acra.ACRA.init (ACRA.java:230)
  at org.acra.ACRA.init (ACRA.java:156)
  at org.acra.ACRA.init (ACRA.java:139)
  at com.myapp.MyApplication.attachBaseContext (MyApplication.java:126)
  at android.app.Application.attach (Application.java:224)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication (Instrumentation.java:1128)
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication (LoadedApk.java:1156)
```

Comment: `attachBaseContext` is the recommended place for initialization. Issues in production which aren't visible are most often caused by proguard. Test with proguard enabled to confirm that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information at https://github.com/ACRA/acra/issues/630, my solution was using this:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    ACRA.init(this, new ConfigurationBuilder(this).build(), false);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

In the logs, I can see `LOGCAT` showing this line:

```
08-18 16:31:50.489 I/ACRA    (11890): ACRA is enabled for com.myapp, initializing...
```

The initialization is successful now.